# C# timer_Tick() countdown counts down in 2 steps

Tags: c#

I'm trying to program a program which opens a form on a button click. This form has a label with a countdown in it. The main form has a button which does the following:

```
private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> ips = new List<string>();

    if (pcTreeView.SelectedNodes.Count > 1)
    {
        foreach (RadTreeNode node in machinesTreeView.SelectedNodes)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode client in xdoc.SelectNodes("/clients/client"))
            {
                if (node.Text == client["clientShortName"].InnerText)
                {
                    string ipAddress = client["clientIP"].InnerText;
                    ips.Add(client["clientIP"].InnerText);
                    clientNodeList.Add(node);
                }
            }
        }

        MsgBox msgbox = new MsgBox();
        msgbox.ipAddressCollection = ips;
        msgbox.Tag = "test";
        msgbox.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Then it opens the second form. The code for my countdown is the following:

```
int timeLeft = 45;
public List<string> ipAddressCollection { get; set; }

private void MsgBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;

    foreach (string ipAddress in ipAddressCollection)
    {
        if (this.Tag.ToString() == "test")
        {
            if (rebootShutdownTime > 0)
            {
                timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
                infoLabel.Text = "Countdown: " + timeLeft.ToString();
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: The countdown counts down in 2 steps (e.g. 20 - 18 - 16 etc. instead of 20 - 19 - 18 - 17 etc.). In debugging mode it counts correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What if you refresh the label after every tick? `infoLabel.Refresh();`

Comment: Probably in "release" you got 2 connections so it subtracts twice from timeLeft. Maybe you should move the `timeLeft = timeLeft - 1` outside the `for` statement.

Comment: foreach is running twice. Check it by debugging.

Comment: Ah because I got two items in the list. If I'd have 3 items in it, it would counts down 3. Thanks :)

Comment: Is this a Winforms or Webforms APP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code section below the following line smells:

```
foreach (string ipAddress in ipAddressCollection)
```

You are simply decrementing the `timeLeft` for each `ipAddress`. So if you have 45 strings in `ipAddressCollection` timeLeft will be zero even in the first tick.